# reports in purchas order

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

please give me the steps to create a report in purchase order with my new module.i created two files views/purchase_report.xml and Ship/purchase_report.xml.where ship is my module name.

and this is my Ship/purchase_report.xml

```
  <report
            id="custom_report_without_prices"
            model="purchase.order"
            string="purchases"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="Ship.purchase_report"
            attachment_use="False"
            file="Ship.purchase_report"
        />
```

what are the additional steps needed to add the report in purchase order.now there is no errors,but the report is not showing in print option for purchase order.what is the purpose of rml files and some documentation tells about adding a report folder to the module.please give me the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-custom-reports-odoo-8/ 
this link solved my issue.we need only two xml's to create a report